# C++ template argument to refer to type defined within that template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct TemplateClass {
  class DefaultU {
    T foo;
    /* ... */
  };
  U bar;
  T& baz;
  /* ... */
};
```

And I would like the default value for `U` to be `TemplateClass<T>::DefaultU`.

I *could* take `DefaultU` outside of `TemplateClass`, and make it a template, but I think it belongs inside.

Is that possible?

I realise the implication of what I'm asking, when written out in full, looks something like this:

```
template<typename T>, typename U = TemplateClass<T, TemplateClass<T, TemplateClass<T, ...>::DefaultU>::DefaultU>::DefaultU>
TemplateClass {
  /* ... */
}
```

But maybe there's a short-cut or workaround for that... like making the default type something (eg., `void`) that I can detect and replace with `DefaultU` as needed.

Comment: Its not going to work that way, `DefaultU` would not have been defined within its use as a template argument.

Comment: You said "I think it belongs inside" -- can you explain why? `TemplateClass` is a class template that depends on two parameters, `T` and `U`, so anything inside it also depends on both. If `DefaultU` in fact only depends on `T`, that most likely means it does *not* belong inside the definition of `TemplateClass`.

Comment: Templates cannot have circular references like that.

Comment: I don't understand.. Does this satisfy the problem? http://ideone.com/DUaU60 or http://ideone.com/XWQZ23 or http://ideone.com/hBOS4c

Comment: @jogojapan, I think `DefaultU` belongs inside `TemplateClass` because that's the only context in which it's relevant.  I need it to implement a shim that returns `false` when the utility provided by `U` is irrelevant and so hasn't been implemented externally.  That shim class has no reason to exist in the rest of the world, so it's `TemplateClass`'s business and nobody else's.  However this is transitional code, and I hope the problem will eventually be eliminated when I'm done refactoring.

Comment: @Brandon, I think the second one won't work because of the requirements (hidden in ellipses) of the way U is used which stop me driving it with a trivial type.  The first one was the first thing I tried but the compiler rejected it with errors I didn't bother to read because I didn't expect it to work.  It's possible I just made a stupid typo and threw out that option prematurely.

Comment: @Brandon, it looks like those solutions still don't give a viable _default_ for the instantiation of `TemplateClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is *[it]* possible *[to refer to a member typedef of a class template within the template parameter list of that template]*?

No.

> maybe there's a short-cut or workaround for that... like making the default type something (eg., void)

If void isn't an acceptable type for `U` (or if void is a valid `U` only for specializations for which `DefaultU` is also void), then you could indeed use that as a default, and instead of using `U` directly, you would use conditional member type alias:

```
using u_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_void<U>::value, DefaultU, U>::type;
```

This allows you to define `DefaultU` within the class template.

Instead of void, you could use a custom empty "tag" type for the default. That makes the conditional type slightly more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Writing out [user2079303's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420730/2417578) in full for completeness:

```
template<typename T, typename U_arg = void>
struct TemplateClass {
  class DefaultU {
    T foo;
    /* ... */
  };
  using U = typename std::conditional<
                       std::is_void<U_arg>::value,
                       DefaultU,
                       U_arg
                     >::type;
  U bar;
  T& baz;
  /* ... */
};
```

And with that it's possible to instantiate either `TemplateClass<Foo, FooBar>` explicitly, or `TemplateClass<Foo>` with an implicit `::DefaultU` class in place of `FooBar`.